# Resizing partitions in the installer

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I am new to Linux. I have a Toshiba Satellite M45-S265 with Windows Vista home 32 bit installed.

I made a live boot CD with Linux distro (Lubuntu 15.10 i386.iso).

I booted into Linux installer and it asked to install in the "Something Else" section and to resize my local disk without keeping windows Vista partitions.

So that I can install other Linux distros and keep my files. I don't know how to resize the partitions and what partitions to resize.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 0):

- Boot into Windows Vista
- Right click on "computer" and click "manage"
- click on "disk management"
- select the disk where you want ubuntu to be installed
- right click and click "shrink". This will take some of the free space of your disk and creates a separate partition
- enter the amount of space for the new partition (50000mb or 50GB)
- perform a quick format select NTFS
- remember the drive letter of the new empty partition
- insert ubuntu installation disc and restart
- click install ubuntu
- choose something else
- on the dropdown menu, select the newly created partition and INSTALL
- choose ext4

Comment: Do not create partitions with Windows. It may convert to dynamic partitions which is Microsoft proprietary and does not work with Linux. But do use Windows own tools to shrink NTFS partition and reboot immediately so it can run chkdsk. If you only have used 3 primary partitions then you can create the extended and can have as many logical partitions as you want. But we need to see current partitions post this: `sudo parted -l` from Ubuntu live installer.

Comment: Thank You Jay Mark Paredes Estrera, I am going to try this ...very slowly. I appreciate thew advice and help. Thank You.

Comment: Thank You oldfred, for the advice , I will look  and remember the help that you have given me.

Comment: oldfred and Jay Mark Paredes Estrera. I ran that command (sudo parted -1) in the Linux terminal, and it responded back with " invalid option--'1' "  usage parted  [ -hlmsv] [a<align] [DEVICE [COMMAND [PARAMETERS]]...]

Comment: I opened GParted and I have 2 partitions. (Partition 1) :NTFS>> /dev/sda1  >>size:149.04 GiB used : 11.06  unused:137.98GiB. ( Partition 2) : >>UNALLOCATED size: 10.34